# Dynamic sized text with ellipsis

Tags: css, overflow, ellipsis

I have a header and description text within a fixed-size container which I want on the same line.

Both have dynamic width.

I want the description (which is generally a lot longer) to appear with an ellipsis when it overflows the container.

This is what I have so far: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/PTQ9G/2/).

### markup

```
<div>
    <span class="header">Some dynamic-width header</span>
    <span class="desc">Some dynamic-width description which - when long enough - should end with a ellipsis</span>
</div>
```

### css

```
div
{
    width: 400px;
    max-width: 400px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #952262;
    color: #111;
}
.header
{
    font-weight: bold;
    float:left;
}
.desc
{
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 100%;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out.

I needed `display:block` on the .desc class

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/PTQ9G/5/)**

### css

```
div
{
    width: 400px;
    max-width: 400px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #952262;
    color: #111;
}
.header
{
    font-weight: bold;
    float:left;
}
.desc
{
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: block; 
}
```