# How to get long text and button side by side

Tags: html, css

I am trying to trim my text and near the text, there should be a button....but both must be in a same line. This is what I have:

```
<div style="width:200px;border:1px solid green">
    <div style="white-space:nowrap;overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">sdasdasdasdsadasdasdsadsadsaddsa</div>
    <button>aaa</button>
</div>
```

also available at http://jsfiddle.net/AbmqS/, but I need text and button on same row and button must be visible.

How to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to place display:block on the text with the ellipsis.

I once learned this the hard way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125327/dynamic-sized-text-with-ellipsis).

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/AbmqS/20/)**

### Markup

```
<div class="container">
    <button>aaa</button>
    <div class="text">sdasdasdasdsadasdasdsadsadsaddsa</div>    
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.container
{
  width:200px;
  border:1px solid green; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
.text
{
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: block; 
}
button
{
    float: right;    
}
```

Comment: That is what I looking for. But when there are no enough letters...the button stay on right side....is there any possibility how to achieve that this button will be right near the text?

Comment: Yea I will but I have another question and I dont want to spam this forum =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div style="width:200px;border:1px solid green">
    <div style="width: 150px;white-space:nowrap;overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; float: left">sdasdasdasdsadasdasdsadsadsaddsa</div>
    <button style="float: left">aaa</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Use css instead of inline styles.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most simple solutions in your case is:

- Move the button inside the div
- Remove **width:200px;**
- Add **float:left;** style to the div.

See the following fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ggMPw/

```
<div style="float:left;border:1px solid green"> 
  <div style="white-space:nowrap;overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">sdasdasdasdsadasdasdsadsadsaddsa
     <button>aaa</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't allow text-overflow to work which is what it looks like the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a nice way to do this unless you can specify the width of the button and/or the text.

http://jsfiddle.net/jaypeagi/AbmqS/12/

```
div * {
    float:left;
}
div div {
    width: 150px;
}
button{
    width: 50px;
}
div br {
    clear:both;
}
```

However, if you meant to make the text 200px with the button as an additional width to this, its a bit nicer and you can do this:

http://jsfiddle.net/jaypeagi/AbmqS/15/

```
div * {
    float:left;
}
div div {
    width: 200px;
}
button{

}
div br {
    clear:both;
}

body > div {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use table

```
<div style="width:200px;border:1px solid green">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 150px;white-space:nowrap;overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis; float: left">sdasdasdasdsadasdasdsadsadsaddsa

        </td>
        <td>
            <button>aaa</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is link to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AbmqS/16/)